# How to import the articles into wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

There is a mysql db named `articles` ,the table name is article ,three fields in it:`subject`,`content`,`category`. There are two values for the field `category` ,one is `c1`, other is `c2`.
There are two categories `c1` and `c2` in my wordpress.
Now how to import all records in the table `article` in `articles` db into my wordpress wp_posts table in mywp (mysql database name for the wordpress).

```
show columns from wp_posts;

  +-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| ID                    | bigint(20)          | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| post_author           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| post_date             | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_date_gmt         | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_content          | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_title            | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_excerpt          | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_status           | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | publish             |                |
| comment_status        | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | open                |                |
| ping_status           | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | open                |                |
| post_password         | varchar(20)         | NO   |     |                     |                |
| post_name             | varchar(200)        | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| to_ping               | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| pinged                | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_modified         | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_modified_gmt     | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_content_filtered | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_parent           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| guid                  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| menu_order            | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| post_type             | varchar(20)         | NO   | MUL | post                |                |
| post_mime_type        | varchar(100)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| comment_count         | bigint(20)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

There are so many fields in wp_posts, only 3 fields in my source db.
The most important things are :
1.How to set guid when to insert records?
2.After records in the articles db whose category is `c1` are inserted into wp_posts table, how to make the records displayed under the category `c1` in wordpress?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this a few times and I assure you it's more than a simple `INSERT` into `wp_posts`. Posts have enough extras that it's just much quicker to use a plugin to do it; namely time consuming is correctly formatted slug, formatted date/time, references in the `wp_term_relationships` table to note categories, and any meta data you have. Personally, I prefer [WP Ultimate CSV Importer Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/), but there's a number of options out there ([several briefly explained here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82402/31367)).

Essentially, you'll export your data from your `article` table into a .csv file, then upload to file using a WP Importer. The one I mentioned looks at the cvs headers and allows you to map them manually to each WordPress-specific field. For example, map your `content` column to the `post_content` column.

The main thing to watch for is that you for sure export/import all of the information you have in one go - it's a fair bit more difficult to override existing data (though I believe you can do it), ensure the csv file includes column headers, and **backup WordPress before you import** anything because it's a mess to manually fix things later.

If you *really* want to do it manually, your best bet is lots of research and trial/error to see what fields are required. Most of it's pretty straight forward, just time consuming; `post_content`, `post_title` are just text fields, `author` is (probably) the admin's user ID, date/time is just `NOW()` formatted `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, and on. I'd look through the existing plugins and grab their code as a primary point of reference, but then why not just use their plugin since they already did the work and are offering it for free to you.

To answer your last two questions more directly,

1. The `guid` is the Globally Unique Identifier. Ideally, it's a unique ID across the internet; specific to your domain and to each post/page/etc on your site. It's mostly used so RSS feeds know what content is new and after it's been created as unique, [you should never change it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note).
2. You'll need to insert posts into wp_posts then get the ID of the newly inserted post and add it to the `wp_term_relations` table along with the ID of the category you want which can be found in the `wp_terms` table.

[Here's some more detais on the overall layout of the WordPres database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use the plugin called [Wordpress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/).

Comment: No , my intuition tells me that it is simple to do that with mysql command ,problem is i can't .